How to write a letter for reach out prospective phd advisor
I am a master student majored in mathmaticas and I'm going to reach out professor to be my prospective phd advisor. How to write this email? What need I write in it? How many words is proper?
Need I say any request like "I want be interviewed" in the litter?

Please search our archives, there are many, many versions of this question already out there. Then come back if you have a more specific question. At the risk of self-promotion, my answer here may be useful to you.
